# PostgreSQL query is much slower from client than from server

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I work in a small company (~ 15 employees) and we have a postgreSQL database stored in our company server.

I usually run queries from my own computer (that I will call 'the client' hereafter), and fetching results does not usually increase query durations dramatically.

However, today, I ran a request from the client, and it took 2 hrs 10 min to run. But I was very surprised to see the following on my screen:

```
Query returned successfully in 10:35 minutes.
```

I thought that this means that the calculation on the server itself lasted 10 minutes, and that the rest of the time (2 hours...) was only for fetching results from the server to the client.

Then, I tried running another query from the client (namely, executing the function `pgr_CreateTopology` to find the vertices of a graph). I did not run it until the end, but it seemed to be very slow: only 6000 vertices were created in 20 minutes and there are about 300'000 vertices in my graph, which means that the query would have taken approximately 15 hours to complete.

I aborted this query and I ran it again, but this time, from the server. And it completed in 12:42 minutes.

A dozen minutes when ran from the server, a dozen hours when ran from the client... How to explain such a performance difference?

I want to mention again the fact that usually, with short queries, when I use EXPLAIN I never find fetching results to represent most of the query duration, since we have a fast internal network.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040873/postgresql-query-10x-slower-in-a-different-client?rq=1 ?

Comment: @Johan in the `postgresql.conf` file, I have `#ssl = off`.

Comment: Oh I get it now. The hash character `#` before `ssl = off` means that this is a commented line, i.e. it's not taken account of. I removed the hash and now the parameter `ssl` is actually set to `off`. I am running the query again from the client and it's indeed much faster. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the problem was the same than in this question: [Postgresql: Query 10x slower in a different client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040873/postgresql-query-10x-slower-in-a-different-client?rq=1)

Turning SSL compression off by setting `ssl = off` in the `postgresql.conf` configuration file, and then restarting the postgreSQL server, solved the issue.